# jquery mobile flip toggleswitch to update list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to update a list by using a toggle switch, but I cannot find the solution. Any inputs from you guys? any hint will be very appreciated :).

Important: the `.ui-li` list id is `#myListView` which is populated from the server with `data-value` as `+item.Gender+` "female" or "male". I want to create a code that if user uses toggle off for male, then the list will update by only showing "female" value in the `li`. and vice versa.

So far, I have this (no working) code:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page-settings", function (){
$("#flip-1").on("change", function (){
    if ($(this).val() == "off"){
        $("#myListView").val($(item.Gender =="female")).listview( "refresh" );
    }

});

});
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<div data-role="content" id="settingsPanel">
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="menSelector" >    
        <label for="flip-1">Men</label>
        <select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider"data-mini="true" class="genderSelect">
            <option value="off"></option>
            <option selected="selected" value="on"></option>
        </select> 
    </div>

    <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="womenSelector" >  
        <label for="flip-2">Women</label>
        <select name="flip-2" id="flip-2" data-role="slider"data-mini="true" class="genderSelect">
            <option value="off"></option>
            <option selected="selected" value="on"></option>                
        </select>           
    </div>
```

Comment: using `.val()` with listview isn't correct. Pls explain what you want to do. Add a list item with gender?

Comment: Hi @omar, I have updated the question. Hope it is more clear :). Thanks for the observation.

Comment: Hi @cytasos, Thank you! Yeah, the list is populated via PHP mysql, and I have a list already working with both, female and male. But from the settings page I have the toggle options for gender. My question is how to refresh the list when user toggles gender options.

Comment: ok, i get it now, i thought you wanted to fetch data not clear the list of males or girls. well its very easy, you have an answer below. see if there is a TRI state button out there so you can have a middle state instead of having 2 buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your li has a data attribute for gender, e.g.

```
<li data-gender="female"></li>
```

Then when you flip a switch, first show all listitems:

```
$('#myListView li').show();
```

Then hide either male or female:

```
$('#myListView li[data-gender="male"]').hide();
```

**UPDATE:**

So, given your flip switches, handle the change event and call a function called `ShowList()` on each change. In ShowList() check which flip switches are on, and if one is on and the other is off, hide the gender that is off:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
    $("#flip-1").on("change", function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "off"){
            $("#flip-2").val("on").slider( "refresh" );
        }

        ShowList();
    });
    $("#flip-2").on("change", function(){
            if ($(this).val() == "off"){
            $("#flip-1").val("on").slider( "refresh" );
        }

        ShowList();
    });
});

function ShowList(){
    var m = $("#flip-1").val() == "on";
    var f = $("#flip-2").val() == "on";
    $('#myListView li').show();
    if (m && !f) {
        $('#myListView li[data-gender="female"]').hide();
    } else if (!m && f) {
        $('#myListView li[data-gender="male"]').hide();
    }
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/dsmhvtpm/2/)**

Comment: Thanks @ezanker. I am appending the value for +item.gender+ so the list comes either with female or male as a result data. My question is how to refresh that list using a flip-toggle. Sorry i have not been able to explain myself efficiently.

Comment: @user3356128, OK, I have updated the answer to use your flip switches.

Comment: you are the best! Thank you so much. I was breaking my head trying to find a solution.